# SPA DTM analytics pagename issue

Tags: analytics, single-page-application, adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

I am using Angular SPA with DTM.Using custom event based rules, I am able to get all my data including pageName, v41,v42 as correct. Now inside adobe editor, i am storing pagename to **s.pageName** and some hard-coded value to **s.server**. I have verified that all my data is correctly populating using **OMNIBUG** tool as server,pageName, v41 and v42.

**Problem** is coming in Omniture reporting, as server and page data are not coming through. Page-name data only showing **SPA homepage** in all page visits and server also coming as default from s.code and not the one i am passing from s.server. eVar/prop are all coming fine.Even if I do prop40=s.pageName/prop41=s.server, then in omniutre reporting i am seeing correct data populating in prop40/prop41 but not under **Page** and **server**. And again I cant use prop40/prop41 for pagename/server as its not a correct way to follow and **PAGE-VISITS** are **ZERO** in that case.

Any help how to get data in page/server in omniture for SPA or anything wrong in my implementation? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you really do see the correct values in Omnibug (or more specifically, network request to Adobe collection server), then the issue is not in the code.

- Check against another AA hit debugger. Possible Omnibug is somehow bugging out. There are a ton of alternatives out there. Adobe Experience Cloud Debugger. Observepoint. Charles Proxy. Fiddler. Or just use the browser dev tool network tab (what I usually do as a backup).
- Make sure you are looking in the correct report suite. Perhaps your data is being sent to a dev report suite, and you are looking at prod report suite, or visa versa?
- Check to see if you have any **Processing Rules** that are overriding your values.
- Contact your Adobe Rep to check if there are any **VISTA Rules** present for the report suite, that are overriding your values.

If you have verified none of the above is the case, then sorry, but it sounds like the issue must really be in your code, but there is a problem with your QA method (e.g. maybe you are looking at the wrong AA request, or something).

**Update:**

Based on your comment:

> Earlier, i was making s.tl() call, but replacing it with s.t() call
>   resolved my problem for data was not populating
>   pageName/server/page-views in Omniture and now it is. But the current
>   problem is we need PageName on all SPA clicks (can be achieved by
>   s.t() call ) , but the page-Views are not needed on all clicks. So,
>   its like link-tracking needed only but with PageName data. I am
>   struggling not to populate page-views on a s.t() call or vice-versa
>   how to get PageName populated on s.tl() call. Again, omnibug shows all
>   requests just fine but the issue comes in reports in omniture

When Adobe processes a hit, it wipes `pageName` for `s.tl` calls, as that's how it determines whether to count the request as a page view or not. If you want to see page name even for `s.tl` calls, the common practice is to dupe the `pageName` value to a `prop` or `eVar` and send in with the `s.tl` call, and look at that report. In fact, most clients I work with don't even use the native pages report, and instead use the (usually `eVar`) report.

Comment: Earlier, i was making s.tl() call, but replacing it with s.t() call resolved my problem for data was not populating pageName/server/page-views in Omniture and now it is. But the current problem is we need PageName on all SPA clicks (can be achieved by s.t() call ) , but the page-Views are not needed on all clicks. So, its like link-tracking needed only but with PageName data. I am struggling not to populate page-views on a s.t() call or vice-versa how to get PageName populated on s.tl() call. Again, omnibug shows all requests just fine but the issue comes in reports in omniture

Comment: @TarunPrakash Okay I see.  When Adobe processes a hit, it wipes `pageName` for `s.tl`  calls, as that's how it determines whether to count the request as a page view or not. If you want to see page names even for `s.tl` calls, you should dupe the `pageName` value to a `prop` or `eVar` to be sent in with the `s.tl` call.

Comment: yes, that solution for storing pageName in prop/eVar works fine. But the requirement is to use only PAGE variable in Omniture. I am looking into if i find any solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: @TarunPrakash ok well as mentioned, Adobe strips pageName while processing if it's an s.tl call. You cannot change this. If you insist on only looking at native pages reports, you have to make it an s.t call, and that will increment page views. That's how Adobe Analytics works.